# Correct usage of phrasal verb [knock sb/sth down]

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I was doing a comprehension and I was to identify the adjective in a sentence.:

The piano was knocked down to the highest bidder.

I identified the adjective but could not understand the question correctly. *Knock down* is usually used as 
the cost was *knocked down* to £20

So how can piano be knocked down *to someone*?

Comment: Please carefully review the [edits](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/178360/edit) I made and make sure they are satisfactory. Also, please review the formatting tips [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Dr Sitecore has provided the right answer. But please call it a 'verbal idiom'. The term 'phrasal verb' is misleading -- it's a misnomer.

Answer (score 2):

[To knock down](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/knock%20down) has other definitions.
This is the one that you need:

> To declare sold at an auction, as by striking a blow with a gavel.